# How do I get this if script to work in js and html?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple HTML game, but I have to use a little bit of javascript in order to make it work. However, I keep on making some sort of mistake, causing the js to not work. Basically, when you hover over a link, it gives you an alert, so I'm trying to make it to where after you hover over it once, it won't alert you again until the page reloads. However, it doesn't seem to be working. If anyone has any fixes, please answer this with the fix.

```
let hover1 = 0;

function hoverAlert() {
    if (hover1 === 0) {
        alert('Test Alert');
    }
    let hover1 = 1;
}
```

I tried the above script, expecting it to only show the alert, but instead, it wouldn't show me an alert at all.

Comment: You have a mistake in your code. Don't redefine `hover1` to local scope with `let`. Remove it and your js error will go away and your alert will show.

Comment: so, that `hoverAlert` function never alerts? did you *call* the function? did you check the browser *developer* tools console for errors?

Comment: the first and  the second  `hover1` may have the same name, but they are two differents elements.

Answer (score 0):

The `let` keyword should only be used for declaring variables. Your usage of `let` on the first line is okay, but when changing the variable's value, you should not use `let`. The line should look like this: `hover1 = 1;`.

Also, the fact that you're not getting an alert most likely means that the function is not being called in the first place. Make sure that your link tag has the `onmouseenter` attribute and that it points to the `hoverAlert` function.

The last issue is that you shouldn't use a link (The anchor tag or `<a>` tag) unless it will redirect someone to a different page or a different part of the current webpage, and instead you should use a button (`<button>`) or just an ordinary text tag (`<p>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<span>`, etc...).